# Clear Duplicates based on First Column VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Hi is there a way to Clear duplicates based on Name?
Last time I already asked how to clear duplicates and here's the output

```
Col 2    | Col 1
Person 1 | 1. Question 1
         | 2. Question 2
         | 3. Question 3
-------------------------
Person 2 | 1. Question 1
         | 2. Question 2
         | 3. Question 3
-------------------------
Person 3 | 1. Question 1
         | 2. Question 2
         | 3. Question 3
```

I add another column which is column 3 where it can see the status.

```
Col 2    | Col 1         | Col 3
Person 1 | 1. Question 1 | CLEAN
         | 2. Question 2 | CLEAN
         | 3. Question 3 | CLEAN
-------------------------
Person 2 | 1. Question 1 | CLEAN
         | 2. Question 2 | CLEAN
         | 3. Question 3 | CLEAN
-------------------------
Person 3 | 1. Question 1 | CLEAN
         | 2. Question 2 | CLEAN
         | 3. Question 3 | CLEAN
```

I want it to be like this:

```
Col 2    | Col 1         | Col 3
Person 1 | 1. Question 1 | CLEAN
         | 2. Question 2 | 
         | 3. Question 3 | 
-------------------------
Person 2 | 1. Question 1 | CLEAN
         | 2. Question 2 | 
         | 3. Question 3 | 
-------------------------
Person 3 | 1. Question 1 | CLEAN
         | 2. Question 2 | 
         | 3. Question 3 |
```

by the way, here's the code:

```
Sub RemoveDups(src As Range, dst As Range)
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, tmp, temp()
' Copy source range
temp = src.Value
' Sort data
For i = LBound(temp, 1) To UBound(temp, 1) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(temp, 1)
        If (temp(i, 2) > temp(j, 2)) Or ((temp(i, 2) = temp(j, 2)) And (temp(i, 1) > temp(j, 1))) Then
            tmp = temp(i, 1)
            temp(i, 1) = temp(j, 1)
            temp(j, 1) = tmp
            tmp = temp(i, 2)
            temp(i, 2) = temp(j, 2)
            temp(j, 2) = tmp
        End If
    Next j
Next i
' Clear vertical dups
For i = UBound(temp, 1) - 1 To LBound(temp, 1) Step -1
    If temp(i + 1, 2) = temp(i, 2) Then
        temp(i + 1, 2) = ""
    End If
Next i
' Swap columns
For i = LBound(temp, 1) To UBound(temp, 1)
    tmp = temp(i, 1)
    temp(i, 1) = temp(i, 2)
    temp(i, 2) = tmp
Next i
' Store result
dst.Value = temp
End Sub
```

I tried to add under **'clear vertical dups**

```
If temp(i + 1, 3) = temp(i, 3) Then
        temp(i + 1, 3) = ""
End If
```

but it gives me this output:

```
Col 2    | Col 1         | Col 3
Person 1 | 1. Question 1 | CLEAN
         | 2. Question 2 | 
         | 3. Question 3 | 
-------------------------
Person 2 | 1. Question 1 | 
         | 2. Question 2 | 
         | 3. Question 3 | 
-------------------------
Person 3 | 1. Question 1 | 
         | 2. Question 2 | 
         | 3. Question 3 |
```

Help me!! Thanks!

Comment: Hum, Why is `col 1` between `col 2` and `col 3`? It is unintuitive, to say the least. Also, unrelated to your problem but it will avoid future ones, you want to `Dim` you variables as `Long` and not as `Integer`.

Comment: Hi @cybernetic.nomad, I swapped `col 1` and `col 2` to easily identify the person's name :)

Answer (score 0):

Inject 3 lines of code in your vertical clearing block immediately after the For statement.

```
' Clear vertical dups
For i = UBound(temp, 1) - 1 To LBound(temp, 1) Step -1 
    If ((temp(i + 1, 2) = temp(i, 2)) And (temp(i + 1, 3) = temp(i, 3))) Then
        temp(i + 1, 3) = ""
    End If
    If temp(i + 1, 2) = temp(i, 2) Then
        temp(i + 1, 2) = ""
    End If
Next i
```